# How do I pass a CollectionData variable from the detail page to other pages in a Xamarin App?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using the Xamarin.Forms Tabs template to create a basic app for historical society.

I'm using the CollectionData page (ItemsPage) to link through to the ItemDetailPage.

I want to then link from ItemDetailPage to another page (MapPage) that retains the ItemID so it will load the correct variables from the DataStore for a map location. So essentially I want to do:

ItemsPage > ItemDetailPage > MapPage

How do I move the ItemID between ItemDetailPage and MapPage?

I've loaded the data into my MapViewPage ViewModels page:

```
using Paston_Design_2.Models;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Paston_Design_2.ViewModels
{
    [QueryProperty(nameof(ItemId), nameof(ItemId))]
    public class MapViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string itemId;
        private string text;
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Text
        {
            get => text;
            set => SetProperty(ref text, value);
        }

        public string ItemId
        {
            get
            {
                return itemId;
            }
            set
            {
                itemId = value;
                LoadItemId(value);
            }
        }
        public async void LoadItemId(string itemId)
        {
            try
            {
                var item = await DataStore.GetItemAsync(itemId);
                Id = item.Id;
                Text = item.Text;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to Load Item");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the codebehind for my ItemDetailPage, added this link:

```
namespace Paston_Design_2.Views
{
    public partial class ItemDetailPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ItemDetailPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new ItemDetailViewModel();
        }
        private async void Map_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(Map)}?{nameof(MapViewModel.ItemId)}");
        }
    }
}
```

But if I add ItemID to to the end of the await command (which I'd like to do to keep the Shell Stack and navigation links), it's not recognised:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(Map)}?{nameof(MapViewModel.ItemId)}={itemId}");
```

I realise I'm probably missing the obvious, but I can't find any tutorials that specifically address this issue (probably due to my inexperience with the Xamarin terminology), and any help would be much appreciated, even if it's a link to a resource that lays it out.

Annoyingly I've noticed that if I mess with the code on the ItemDetailPage (such as duplicating one of the image buttons) it works on the VM! But then it stops working on the next compilation.

Just adding some images to clarify what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: This is the ItemPage]

[image: Second Screen is the ItemDetailPage]

[image: Third is the next page in the stack, which I want to pull the ItemID into so I can use it to call information from that record]

Comment: how are you passing the ItemID to ItemDetailPage?  The same mechanism should work for any other page

Comment: You could create a new project with Shell template. It have the details about how to navigate with itemId. If you want to use the code `Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(Map)}?{nameof(MapViewModel.ItemId)}={itemId}");`, the itemId need to be passed.

Comment: I've taken my Map pages/views code directly from the ItemDetailPage in a bid to replicate the method, but it's not working, most likely due to the fact that I'm using code that takes a selected item and trying to use it where the data isn't coming from a list.

What I need is to:

1. Isolate the ItemID 
2. Create a var for that ItemID in the .cs page above the Navigation code
3. Place the variable in the link

I'm just having a bit of trouble with the syntax and wondered if this had been done before with an example.

Comment: If you could create a ItemID, the navigation would work.